# using xml parsing and getting The requested resource does not support http method POST

Tags: android

I am new to android, I am using xml parsing in my app.And I followed follwing link:
    http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial.In my activty i am using following code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.practicetests);

    lvPracticeTests=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.practicetestslist);
    btnBack=(Button)findViewById(R.id.back);

    btnBack.setOnClickListener(this);

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Log.e("xml",xml);
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
Log.e("xml",xml);
}
```

But I am getting following error in logcat:This is xml value in logcat:
    Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Replace `HttpPost post= new HttpPost(URL);`

into

```
HttpGet get=new HttpGet(URL);
```

in your Parser Class

I think your problem will be solved.

Comment: Sorry Bro! I am getting the same result. for this url

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21865/discussion-between-user1905845-and-deepanker-chaudhary)